# rails handle 404 with url redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to use rails to redirect links that I am sure are out there on the internet from an old domain of mine to a new one.

I would like to take address example.com/about ( about will not exist anymore)

and in my application_controller to take the 404, inspect the url and then redirect to

newexample.com/about

what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to the end of your Routes file:

```
map.connect '*path', :controller => 'some_controller', :action => 'some_action'
```

This will catch any 404. Within the controller and action that will handle this route, use `params[:path]` to examine the url. Then you can `redirect_to` based on whatever is contained in `params[:path]`.

Comment: sweet .. think this is what I was looking for.

Comment: In Rails 3 this becomes `match '*path', :controller => 'some_controller', :action => 'some_action'`

Comment: In Rails 4 this becomes `get '*path', :controller => 'some_controller', :action => 'some_action'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [rescue_from](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from).  In your `ApplicationController`, add something like:

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError,       :with => :redirect_missing
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController,  :with => :redirect_missing
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction,      :with => :redirect_missing

def redirect_missing
  redirect_to "http://newexample.com/about"
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know what the Rails 3.1 equivalent is so I can update the answer?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an equivalent (it will be fixed in later versions). In the meantime PortableWorld's answer works fine.