# If No route match then redirect to root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I enter wrong route or if no routes match error comes then  I want to redirect to root_path. How can I do this?

Thank In Advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make this statement the last in your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
match "*path" => redirect("/")
```

The `"*path"` will match anything and will redirect to the root path.

For more info, take a look at [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) and [redirection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) in the official Rails guides.

Comment: This didnt work in passenger. As soon as the passenger starts up ->

     Message from application: You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.
    If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
    If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
      Instead of: match "controller#action"
      Do: get "controller#action" (ArgumentError)

Comment: am on rails 6 and this did not work gave me error 
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"

Answer (score 25):

In Rails 4/5 you can

```
get '*path' => redirect('/')
```

Edit. As pointed out by @VenkatK this should be last route. The way routes ere evaluated is that those on top are more important than those on the bottom.

Comment: It works when we write the above route at the bottom of all the routes

Comment: How could you send a `:notice` alert or `:flash` this way ?

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect a 404 by putting this in your routes file (at the bottom).

```
map.connect '*path', :controller => 'some_controller', :action => 'some_action'
```

To redirect to root you could do this.

```
match "*path" => redirect("/")
```

There is a bit more detail in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233657/rails-handle-404-with-url-redirect) and alternative ways of doing it by capturing the exception.

Answer (score 3):

For the latest Rails 4.2+ the `match` syntax has slightly changed:

Place this at the bottom of your project's `config/routes.rb`

`match '*path', to: redirect('/'), via: :all`

Answer (score 2):

Create the file in 'public/404.html' and redirect to, if path not found:

```
get '*path' => redirect('/404.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition, when you use any of the suggested answers above, you might get an error `You should not use the "match" method in your router without specifying an HTTP method`.

If that is the case, you can add `:via => [:get, :post]` to your redirect:

```
match '*path' => redirect('/'), :via => [:get, :post]
```